# How to redirect if directory does not exist or should not be seen?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using Apache and want to modify my *.conf* file for a website such that:

- If the request comes from my IP `1.2.3.4`, just display the URL/page as requested
- If the request is not from my IP and the directory does not exist, redirect to root
- If the request is not from my IP and the directory is one I don't want to display to anyone (`example.com/secret/`, `example.com/secret2/hidden.html`, etc.), redirect to root

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is not from your .conf file.
Do this:

.htaccess example:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.1 #Replace with IP address you wish to allow
    RewriteRule .* http://www.yourwebsite.com [R=301,L] #Replace webaddress with yours
```

Make this file in the directories you are trying to keep people out of.

Then make a custom 404 page that redirects to root for the non-existant directories.

Comment: "Best way is not from .conf file" - Providing the criteria are fixed then it is more _efficient_ to do this in httpd.conf